# 403 Forbidden error upon adding AdSense to website

Tags: http-status-code-403, adsense, litespeed

I'm getting a 403 error, a forbidden access error on some pages after I have added AdSense to my website. Error sometimes happens to one page, sometimes to other ones, but it has something to do with the sessions ie. the same pages are/are not working in the same browser session. Everything was working perfectly before adding AdSense.

The server used is LiteSpeed.

Comment: Could you get more information from the server error log?

Comment: I am on shared hosting, so unfortunately not.